# Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable

Tags: php, admin, mamp

I'm using MAMP to work on my localhost with a SQL database.

When i'm trying to open my 'PhPMyAdmin' (tools->phpMyAdmin) I get this error

> Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable! MAMP

I googled it and I changed  the permission of the config.inc.php file but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

phpMyAdmin folder has wrong permissions. You need to reset this permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin
```

If you're using MAMP PRO:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /Library/Application\ Support/appsolute/MAMP\ PRO/phpMyAdmin
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the file in your Finder, then open up your terminal type in `sudo chmod 644`, (leaving a space at the end); then drag and drop the file from Finder to your terminal and hit enter.

Still no luck? It could be that your config.inc.php has some invalid PHP in it. Try manually going to `localhost/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` and see if you get an error message. You can also try the server logs in MAMP to see if you get any interesting PHP errors from it.

Answer (score 0):

On MAMP the `phpMyAdmin` folder is now `phpMyAdmin5`. I found that the following solved the problem:

```
sudo chmod 644 /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin5/config.inc.php
```

I basically located the `config.inc.php` file in Finder then dropped it into the Terminal and prefixed this with `sudo chmod 644`  ensuring there is a space after the 644.