# Images Always Take Exactly 5 seconds To Load Regardless Of Image Size (MAMP)

Tags: image, localhost, mamp, paint

I have a situation where images are all taking exactly 5 seconds to load on my localhost. It's not happening on live sites and the pages themselves that are fetching data from a MySQL database all load quickly - it seems it is just the image assets.

**What I find odd is:**

Regardless of image size (the largest image is about 200KB) it is always exactly 5 seconds (see screenshot).

[image: Network tab in Chrome]

When I check with Google's Lighthouse it scores well for performance and these issues aren't being picked up.

The issues seems to be the painting of the image?

It is only happening on the latest version of MAMP.

I've noticed as well that the phpMyAdmin URL has changed to `http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin5/ ...`  I accept this may be versioning URL and not related to the issue but thought I'd mention it.

I also had this following issue which I fixed with the solution given (I don't know if this is related to the problem) [Wrong permissions on configuration file, should not be world writable! MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33277729/mamp-wrong-permissions-on-configuration-file-should-not-be-world-writable-ma)

I've never come across anything like this before, and I can't get my head around why it always takes exactly 5 seconds to load an uncached image (multiple images also take a total of 5 seconds)?

The other questions on here (StackOverflow) about MAMP and page-load relate to general page load and caching issues.

Any suggestions most welcome.

Comment: I face the same issue. Did you find something?

Comment: @Alex  It was a bug in MAMP, when I upgraded to the latest version the problem was solved